# Setup MS Visual Studio for the PAWN language

Tags: visual-studio, programming-languages, ide

I am used to work with MSVS 2008 and 2010 for some time now. I did some projects using C# and C++ but I am still a rookie. 
For my next project I have to develop using the PAWN language and would like to use MSVS as my IDE. I did some research on the subject but since PAWN is not that popular I didn't find any satisfying solution.

My question is if there is a way to configure MSVS to use as IDE for my PAWN project and if how to do it. Probably something like http://www.ironpython.net (?) - but I really don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution for this is to use the Makefile Project template.  You can specify the commands that build, clean and rebuild commands.  You typically only need the build command.  It is up to you to write it, anything goes.  You can add source code files to the project but there is no way to reference them in the build command.  In other words, if you add a new source code file then you'll have to modify the build command by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to use a Makefile project. I got it to work.